# Typescript: transform function arguments to typed object

Tags: typescript, function, arguments

Is there any way to achieve this?

Eg.:

```js
// given
const f = function(a: number, b: string, c: Car /* let's say, it's a class */): any {
    // anything
}

type args = Magic<typeof f>; // <-- need to know this

/*
And that would be:
{
  a: number,
  b: string,
  c: Car
}
*/
```

I've searched with multiple keywords but no result. I found the `Parameters<F>` but that gives me an array of types, not object.

Comment: No, parameter names are essentially unobservable by the type system.  The type `(a: string)=>void` and `(b: string)=>void` are identical, so they intentionally don't allow you to do much with parameter names here.

Comment: How could I miss that? Thanks.